# Android Studio's Emulator doesn't open

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

i'm using Android Studio 2.3.3, and I'm having a issue. The emulator doesn't open. No signal, nothing. It just don't show me anything. When I try to open, it just load the bar in screen's bottom and disappears. Don't open any screen, any window, nothing.

I already tried to delete all SDK and reinstall, but didn't work.

Can anybody help me?

(I was using Android Studio 3.0 Canary 5 before it, if it helps).

---

> **EDIT:**
> I'm using Windows 10 64bit, 8gb RAM, Intel HD graphics 520, Intel Core
> i5-6200U
>
> I already had delete my AVDs and recreated. I also uninstalled and
> reinstalled all the SDK, including all the tools, emulator and
> anything else (as showed in the pic).
>
> I want to run x86.
>
> [sdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh6G0.jpg)
>
> [avd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOcVE.jpg)

Comment: And you created a AVD emulator: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html Also edit your question to tell us which OS are you using as well which ABI are you trying to launch (x86 uses HAXM, armabi is slower but should run everywhere)

Comment: edit your avd and change graphics to software instead of hardware or auto. It is in the advanced settings. click on the **showAdvancedSettings** button and change, that worked for me

Comment: @MorrisonChang done. Any idea?

Comment: 1. Are you under some form of Active Directory management that would prevent the Android emulator? (doubt it but had to ask) 2. Try the Microsoft Visual Studio Emulator for Android: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228279.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Create a new simulator and see if it works. 
I had the same Issue... maybe it happened after updating some build tools ..
It worked For me.